# Why is the mysql Insert command not working for me in python?

Tags: python, mysql

The query is correct but I do not understand why it cannot be added into my database. Please help me thanks. I am a beginner and I can hardly debug this one.

```
    def callback(channel):
    print("\nflame detected\n")

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)#pin if HIGH or LOW
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)       


while True:

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="results")
    #create a cursor for the select
    cur = db.cursor()
    result = instance.read()
    if result.is_valid():
        print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
        print("Temperature: %d F" % ((result.temperature*9/5)+32))
        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

        cel = str(result.temperature)
        far = str((result.temperature*9/5)+32)
        hum = str(result.humidity)
        fla = "No Flame"




    #execute an sql query
    sql = "INSERT INTO res(celsius,fahrenheit,humidity,flame) VALUES('"+cel+"','"+far+"','"+hum+"','"+fla+"')"
    cur.execute(sql)

        # close the cursor
    cur.close()

    # close the connection
    db.close ()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: need to do `db.commit()`?

Comment: Or you could do `db.autocommit = True` *(before any transactions/cursor creations)*. But that might be more dangerous if you forget you enabled it.

Comment: @Torxed which part will i put commit ?

Comment: Try and figure it out? That's part of the learning process to be honest. Being able to figre out where and what part of the puzzle fits where. But the [docs](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/FAQ.html?highlight=commit#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away) are pretty clear on it. *Hint: right after `cur.execute(sql)` is a good time to commit things to the database*

Comment: Don't use string formatting for queries, this is an SQL injection risk. `cur.execute("INSERT INTO res (celsius,fahrenheit,humidity,flame) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (cel, far, hum, fla))`. Then you need `db.commit()` before closing.

Comment: Although I just spotted `MySQL` so it's possible you will need to swap `?` for `%s` because different library wrappers need different binding parameters for _parameterized queries_, but the `%s` in MySQL should not be confused with the old style of string formatting in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ...

```
sql = "INSERT INTO res(celsius,fahrenheit,humidity,flame) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
data = (cel, far, hum, fla)
```

Specifying the need values and making it clearer, also you're missing the `db.commit()`

`cur.execute(sql, data)` with this you have executed the command also passing it's value to `sql`

then after that you can commit your db.

`db.commit()`

then close the connection.